# How to run django's "python manage.py runserver" , celery's "celery -A app_name worker -l info" and redis-server in one command

Tags: python, django, redis, django-celery, circusd

I have recently started with django. And I started doing a small project. I've been using celery with redis worker. And every to use celery and redis I have to run the celery and redis server and then django server. Which is a bit lengthy process. 
I have two questions.
1. Am I doing the right thing by running the servers everytime or are there any other right method to this process?
2. If I'm in the right direction, is there any method to do this?

**I tried circus.ini , but it did not work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use UNIX system:

1. For this purpose you can get along just with **bash**. Just run **celery** and **redis** in background - use `&` command.

```
redis-server & celery -A app_name worker -l info & python manage.py runserver
```

Disadvantage  of this approach - **redis** and **celery** will work in the background even after a shutdown of **django dev server**. So you need to terminate these processes. See [this unix se answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104825) for examples how to do that.

So you can create 2 bash scripts `start.sh` (contains commands with `&`) and `cleanup.sh` (terminate processes) and run them respectively.

For production see **purpose #2**

2. Use **systemd** or **supervisor**. You need to create conf files for your daemons and then run them.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [Yevhenii M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2176485/yevhenii-m)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59418258/1062281), you can start a subshell command with a `trap` to kill all running processes in that subshell when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```sh
(trap "kill 0" SIGINT; redis-server & celery -A app_name worker -l info & python manage.py runserver)
```

or as a more readable multiline command:

```sh
(
    trap "kill 0" SIGINT
    redis-server & 
    celery -A app_name worker -l info &
    python manage.py runserver
)
```

---

Another option is to use a Procfile manager, but that requires installing additional dependencies/programs. Something like [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) or one of it's ports in other languages:

- [forego](https://github.com/ddollar/forego) - Go
- [node-foreman](https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman) - Node.js
- [gaffer](https://github.com/jingweno/gaffer) - Java/JVM
- [goreman](https://github.com/mattn/goreman) - Go
- [honcho](https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho) - python
- [proclet](https://github.com/kazeburo/Proclet) - Perl
- [shoreman](https://github.com/chrismytton/shoreman) - shell
- [crank](https://github.com/arktisklada/crank) - Crystal
- [houseman](https://github.com/fujimura/houseman) - Haskell

(Source: foreman's README)

For this you create a `Procfile` (file in your project root) where you specify which commands to run:

```
redis:  redis-server
worker: celery -A app_name worker
web:    python manage.py runserver
```

Then run `foreman start`